# Web Service response in Visual Basic 6

Tags: web-services, vb6

I have to invoke a Web Service from Visual Basic 6, and and never programed a web service before (i read that VB6 combined with WS aren't very popular here, but it's what it is).

I'm building an example to know how it works, but the WS it's not returning what i'm expecting: a number (it seems that returns a web page in xml format). Maybe it's a simple thing, but i've wasted hours finding a solution and i haven't found anything.

Here is the code:

```
    Dim objDom As Object
    Dim objXmlHttp As Object
    Dim strRet As String
    Dim intPos1 As Integer
    Dim intPos2 As Integer
    Dim strSoapAction As String
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strXml As String

    strUrl = "http://my_file.xsd"
    strSoapAction = "http://web_service_soap"


    strXml = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
   "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" >" & _
     "<soapenv:Body>" & _
       "<entry xmlns=""http://my_file.xsd"">" & _
         "<par1>PARAM_1</par1>" & _
         "<par2>PARAM_2</par2>" & _
       "</entry>" & _
     "</soapenv:Body>" & _
   "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    ' Load XML
    objDom.async = False
    objDom.loadXML strXml

    ' Open the webservice
    objXmlHttp.open "POST", strUrl, False

    ' Create headings
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strSoapAction

    ' Send XML command
    objXmlHttp.send objDom.xml

    ' Get all response text from webservice
    strRet = objXmlHttp.responseText

    ' Close object
    Set objXmlHttp = Nothing

    ' Extract result
    intPos1 = InStr(strRet, "Result>") + 7
    intPos2 = InStr(strRet, "<!--")
    If intPos1 = 7 And intPos2 > 0 Then
        strRet = Mid(strRet, intPos1, intPos2 - intPos1)
    End If

    ' Return result
    PostWebservice = strRet
```

The result is an XML, that seems a web page with an HTTP404 error:

> CTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
>
> ```
> <title>Error 404 Page not found</title>   <link href="/com_errors_html/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet"
> ```
>
> type="text/css" />             window.onload =
>   function(){           var LanguageNav = new String;       }
>
> etc (too long to post)

Thw web service is operational, is the first thing that i discarded.
Any light that you can give me, i'd be grateful.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you're loading the body into an XML object from string and then immediately reading `.xml` back as string. You don't need `objDom` at all. On contrary, when you are reading the response, you are ignoring the parsed `.responseXML` and trying to parse it out yourself.

Comment: Related to your problem, are you sure the web service only accepts SOAP requests? For my VB6-related web services needs I use `setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and pass the parameters as `key=value` pairs.